# Regular expression for data scraping?

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm over-complicating this simple project, but I am trying to learn more about Python, so I thought of this simple app that involves scraping the movie times of all current movies based on the movies listed on google showtimes.

The location is irrelevant, because it pulls up all current movies. I have the code to scrap all the data in the `<span class=info></span>` tag, but it obviously extracts the length of the movie along with a ton of other html data. I only want the movie times.

I am assuming to extract just the movie times, I need some sort of regular expression.

Here is a small snippet of what part of the text information looks like

```
<span class=info>&#8206;2hr 3min&#8206;&#8206; - Rated PG-13&#8
```

I need the hour and the min, nothing else. What is the best way to go about parsing this data from this line of text?

Comment: When I say movie times, I just mean the actual length of the movie, not the associated movie show times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regular expression here, yes. BeautifulSoup will give you a unicode value when you extract the tag text:

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''<span class=info>&#8206;2hr 3min&#8206;&#8206; - Rated PG-13&#8''')
>>> soup.span.get_text()
u'\u200e2hr 3min\u200e\u200e - Rated PG-13'
```

The [U+200e LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK codepoints](http://codepoints.net/U+200e) can be ignored, a regular expression can pick out the time easy enough:

```
import re

time_pattern = re.compile(r'(\d+)hr\s*(\d+)min')

hours, minutes = time_pattern.search(soup.span.get_text()).groups()
```

where the two `\d+` groups match digits followed by `hr` and `min` text respectively, separated by whitespace.

This produces:

```
>>> time_pattern = re.compile(r'(\d+)hr\s*(\d+)min')
>>> hours, minutes = time_pattern.search(soup.span.get_text()).groups()
>>> hours
u'2'
>>> minutes
u'3'
```